# pyqt5で表示したグラフを任意のフォルダー内に保存したい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, pyqt

pyqt5で表示したグラフを選択したフォルダーに保存したいです。まず、次のようなGUIを作成しました。
[image: 画像1]
ここで、Saveのボタンを押したときに次のようなフォルダ選択ダイアログが出て、選んだフォルダ内にグラフが画像データとして保存されるようにしたいです。
[image: 画像2]

以下に、実際に書いたコードを載せます。

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.hide()

        # Just some button 
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save')
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.save)

        # set the layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        btnlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        qw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        qw.setLayout(btnlayout)
        layout.addWidget(qw)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def save(self):
        filename=QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"save folda")

    def plot(self):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        self.axes.plot(data, '*-')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

しかし、46行目のSave関数の中の、フォルダ選択画面を出した後の書き方が分かりません。Plot関数の中でグラフを画像ファイルに直すことができれば、Save関数内で保存ができるような気もしますが、そのやり方も分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

◇ディレクトリを選択して固定のファイル名で保存

```
def save(self):
    from pathlib import Path
    file_name = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    if len(file_name) == 0:
        return
    file_name = str(Path(file_name, "plot.png"))
    self.figure.savefig(file_name)
```

◇ファイル名を入力して保存

```
def save(self):
    from pathlib import Path
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
    if len(file_name) == 0:
        return
    print(file_name)
    file_name = str(Path(file_name).with_suffix(".png"))
    print(file_name)
    self.figure.savefig(file_name)
```

◇参考情報
[pyplot#savefig](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)
[pathlib](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: 詳しい回答ありがとうございます！お陰様で無事に出来ました。